# Creating dynamic XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, mule, dreamweaver

Input XML can change, say if the following XML is coming as input:

```xml
<Root>
    <Fruits></Fruits>
    <FruitsName>
        <Apple></Apple>
        <Mango></Mango>
    </FruitsName>
</Root>
```

than  output should be generated based on a mapping file. 
Here say `Fruits` to be mapped with `F1`.
`FruitsName`  to be mapped with `FN`. 
`Apple` to be mapped with `App`.
`Mango` to be mapped with `Man` which will be present in properties file.

Output:

```xml
<Root>
    <F1> </F1>
    <FN>  
        <App></App> 
        <Man></Man>
    </FN>
</Root>
```

Now if the input XML has different tags than XML should be generated based on 
the mapping file/properties file.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: use dom parser https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: not a very clear question but this looks like one of the tasks XSLT was created for

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an XML to XMl transformation.
You can Make use of XSLT to achieve the output.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using following simple dataweave script:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
Root:{
F1: payload.Root.Fruits,
FN:{
App: payload.Root.FruitsName.Apple,
Man: payload.Root.FruitsName.Mango
}
}
}
```

output as you expect:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Root>
  <F1></F1>
  <FN>
    <App></App>
    <Man></Man>
  </FN>
</Root>
```